# FFmpeg: difference between atrim = a: b and aselect = 'between (t, a, b)'

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, encode, trim

I am starting to learn about ffmpeg and there is an unknown problem so use atrim=a:b or aselect='between(t, a,b)' when you want to trim an audio. 
What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`atrim=a:b` will select starting with timestamp a but drop frames with timestamp `b` or greater.

`aselect='between(t,a,b)'` will select starting with timestamp a; it will select frame with timestamp `b` but drop all frames with a timestamp greater than `b`.

Other than that, they are similar. Timestamps of selected frames will not be reset to start with 0 in either filter.